# php array is printed infinite time using while loop

Tags: php

I know i Can easily do this with a for loop but i am trying to do it in while loop and I get Google infinite times. Why is this? I Knew something was wrong however because i was going over a tutorial on tuts+ I thought it was my mistake. Then I read the comments section of the video and the instructor says sorry I forgot to increment the I.

```
          $month = array('google', 'html5nurse' , 'facebook'); 

          $i = 0;

          while ( $i < 10) {
      echo "<li>$month[$i]</li>";
          }
          ?>
```

Comment: you are not incrementing $i

Comment: You're not incriminating `i`. and i++ after the echo statement

Answer (score 1):

Add i++ after the echo statement.

```
$month = array('google', 'html5nurse' , 'facebook'); 
$i = 0;
while ( $i < 10) {
    echo "<li>$month[$i]</li>";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: That should work, but instead of $i < 10 you can use $i < count($array)

Comment: For this purpose, that's not really necessary.

Comment: Well, once $i > 2 you'll have a Undefined index error.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because `$i` is always equal to 0 in your code.

You need to increment it (as stated in the other solution) for instance using $i++ in the loop.

Note that it's generally better to use `foreach` which will iterate over each element of the array:

```
$months = array('google', 'html5nurse' , 'facebook'); 

foreach($months as $month){
    echo $month."<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> $month = array('google', 'html5nurse' , 'facebook');

```
      $i = 0;

      while ( $i++ < 10) 
      {
        echo "<li>$month[$i]</li>";
      }
      ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `$i++` to increment `$i` and also using `count` so that the loop does not continue after there are no more results in the array.

```
<?php

    $month = array('google', 'html5nurse' , 'facebook'); 

    $i = 0;
    $count = count($month);

    while ($i < $count)
    {
        echo "<li>$month[$i]</li>";
        $i++;

    }
?>
```